# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to use an applet I downloaded. I get the following error when using it

```
Can't load library 'friend'.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:no friend in java.library.path

No resource '/libfriend.so' found.
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the link is not 'large' enough :)

Answer (score 1):

the application is looking for a native library called libfriend.so in your path.  I'm assuming you're on linux, if so and you have the .so file you can add it to your path, if you are on windows you are out of luck.

Comment: I believe that should that not be LD_LIBRARY_PATH rather than PATH